# How to get info Last Run Time, or How Many Times and App has been Executed or Run?

Tags: android

Does Android OS store info on Apps like last run time, or how many times an app was run?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`processCpuUsage`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/battery_history/BatteryHistory.java;h=06f38ae052dcaebf64ee880c9375d124cada1851;hb=HEAD#l535) method of `BatteryHistory` to see how it retrieves a [`Uid.Proc`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/os/BatteryStats.java;h=d114bffe813dd4af27a0cadc43c2a5ebeb15dca1;hb=HEAD#l302) from which you can get the time spent executing user code, the time spent executing system code, the time spent in the foreground, and the number of times a process has been started.

Answer (score 0):

The market only gives you the number of times downloaded and the total install base (i.e. count of users who have not uninstalled the application).

There are a variety of third party dlls that you can use to provide you with analytics regarding app usage.

Flurry is one.  AdMob, now owned by Google, is another.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that isn't what you were asking.  I read your questions as "Does the Android OS store..." -- as in the market.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
long begin = c.getTimeInMillis();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<UsageStats> mListUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, begin, end);
```

Then you can loop through the mListUsageStats objects and call getLastTimeUsed()

```
long lastRunTime = mListUsageStats.get(i).getLastTimeUsed();
```