# Calculate Android Application Runtime

Tags: java, android

I have implemented an app where we can add other apps installed on the phone to the app list and it runs when we click on it. For example, I've added the WhatsApp to my apps list, and when I click this, I want to save the exact time of using WhatsApp after it has stopped.
How can I do this?
I used the Service, AppChecker, and Timer for this, and PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS was also given.
When the app is clicked (in the example above “WhatsApp”), the service runs and the timer starts. And this command checks when the timer stops.
appChecker.getForegroundApp (this) .equals (Package Name)
But the way I implemented it has a problem. Some phones have the following error.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals (java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Have a look at my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51581258/5339154).